# How to convert a textfile containing json data to a json file with all json payloads ordered?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, json

Suppose I have textfile file that has json data in it that looks like the following:

```
1.5405E+13,{2021-02-16T16:40:34.269Z},"{"id":"1234567890","ts":"2021-02-16T11:41:27.517Z",...}"
1.5405E+13,2021-02-17T16:38:04.258Z,"{"id":"1234567890","ts":"2021-02-17T11:48:13.854Z",...}"
1.5405E+13,{2021-02-16T16:38:02.661Z},"{"id":"1234567890","ts":"2021-02-16T03:05:54.714Z",...}"
```

Each json payload has an id field, a timestamp field and several other fields as too. The extra fields aren't really significant here so I'm keeping them as "...". I want to create a script to read from the textfile, convert all data to json and then order that data based on the timestamp field. It's important to note that the prefix of the json data will not always be the same, so I can't use the fact that after say the 38th character I'll have a json in a string.

If I had all the data already in json form this wouldn't be too bad and in fact, I've created a Python script to read from a json file, order the data and write that ordered data, with each payload on a newline, to a textfile. That script is below. I'm just not sure how to do the initial conversion from a textfile that looks like the one above, to json data because of the extra characters before the json data. From there, I can just apply the script below:

```
import json

payloads = open('./ordered_data.json',)
data = json.load(payloads)

data.sort(key=lambda s: s['ts'])

with open('ordered_data.txt', 'w') as f:
    for payload in data:
        json.dump(payload, f)
        f.write("\n")
```

The output of this script is, as required:

```
{"id":"1234567890","ts":"2021-02-16T03:05:54.714Z",...}
{"id":"1234567890","ts":"2021-02-16T11:41:27.517Z",...}
{"id":"1234567890","ts":"2021-02-17T11:48:13.854Z",...}
```

Any advice to do the initial conversation textfile -> json data in this script would be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance! Also, the script also doesn't necessarily have to be in Python. I chose that arbitrarily, I could also do this in node.js.

Comment: If you are absolutely sure that the format of the string is like that, a simple `data = line[38:]` cuts off the first characters of the line.

Comment: @Pietro The format is NOT fixed. As I mentioned in my post: "It's important to note that the prefix of the json data will not always be the same, so I can't use the fact that after say the 38th character I'll have a json in a string."

Comment: Why is that timestamp wrapped into {…} on that first and third line, but not on the second? This is one of those cases again, where the first thing that needs to happen, is a proper slap in the face of whoever created this mess, isn’t it? :-)

Comment: But still, unless there’s more surprises in the data than what we have already seen, you should be able to simply determine the first occurrence of `,"` in each line, the actual JSON data of interest appears to always start after that.

Comment: Yeah, the {} and then the absence of a {} is an example of when we'd see different test data provided. That said, I think determining the first occurrence of `,"` will work. Thanks very much @CBroe